# Llamar ultimos tres valores en Firebase Database Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase

tengo este codigo y me llama la linea "Nodo" que tengo guardado en firebase Database

```
DatabaseReference fReference = database.getReference().child(Lista);
 final StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
    final StringBuilder sp=new StringBuilder();
    verdosis.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            fReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        sb.append(snapshot.getValue().toString());
                        sb.append(System.getProperty("line.separator") );
                    }
                    textViewf.setText(sb.toString());
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });

            }

    });
```

y requiero de solo cargar donde dice Dosis y las ultimas tres guardadas señalada en rojo, alguien me puede ayudar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias!! espero respuesta de como podria hacerlo

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta, ¿usted necesita obtener los últimos tres datos de la Database o la palabra "dosis" de la cadena de texto?

Comment: Asi es los ultimos tres datos guardados de las ultimas tres filas guardadas y el valor señalado en rojo

Answer (score 1):

Estructuraste mal la informacion, en vez de guardar esa data toda junta en un string bajo la pushKey deberias haber guardado debajo de esa push key cada valor por separado, asi, de la siguiente forma lo podes hacer mucho mas facil sin usar StringBuilders.

Para llamar a los ultimos 3 valores basta con usar `limitToLast()` y `orderByChild()` en tu referencia del database

```
DatabaseReference fReference = database.getReference().child(Lista).orderByChild("dosis").limitToLast(3);
```

Doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data?hl=es-419